# vuejs checkbox within a v data table header sorting

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm having some trouble with a project I'm working on. I have some data in a v data table. Header data is being pulled from an api. Within the v data table, I have some checkboxes. These checkboxes are used for the user to select a particular business and/or document number. The user can go ahead and print these to pdf via a button that shows up when a document number is selected.

When a user clicks on a v data header to sort, I'm seeing that all the checkboxes are highlighted, however my button to print pdfs does not show up. I've been doing some reading and it looks as if the checkboxes are not being sorted with the other data in the v data table. I've tried a few things such as clearing the array that holds the checkbox data. Also adding some logic to check to see if the header has been clicked and then calling my function to clear the checkboxes. These solutions do not work.

Here is some of my code. Also this project is build using vue and vuetify 2.6

````
```
````

<v-data-table
dense
:headers="headers"
:page.sync="page"
:items="olpayments"
:search="search"
@click:row="getinfo"
hide-default-footer
:items-per-page="ipp"

````
                    >
                    <template v-slot:top>
                        <v-row>
                        <v-btn v-if="olpayments.length>10" :disabled="btndisabled" dense class="mt-1 ml-8" color="success" @click="showall">{{sar}}</v-btn>
                        <v-divider vertical class="mx-2"></v-divider>
                            <v-text-field
                            dense
                            v-model="search"
                            label="Search "
                            class="mx-4"
                            ></v-text-field>
                        </v-row>
                    </template>
                    <template v-slot:item.prikey="{item}">
                        <v-checkbox
                        v-model="cb"
                        class="cbp"
                        ref="n"
                        :label=item.prikey.toString()
                        :value=item.prikey
                        @click.native.stop
                        ></v-checkbox>
                          <!-- <input type="checkbox" @click.native.stop :value=item.prikey class="cb" v-model="cb">{{item.prikey}} -->
                    </template>
                    
                    <template v-slot:footer>
                        <v-divider></v-divider>
                            <transition name="fade" :duration="{ enter: 500, leave: 0 }">
                                <div v-if="cb.length<1" class="ma-10"><v-btn text disabled > No Items Have Been Selected</v-btn></div>
                            </transition>
                        <transition name="fade" :duration="{ enter: 500, leave: 0 }" >
                            <div v-if="cb.length>0">
                        
                        
                            <v-row>
                            <v-col cols=1>
                                <v-btn @click="submitchecked" elevation="8" height="75" width="80" class="ml-2" dark color="blue darken-3">Submit<br/>All<br/>Checked</v-btn>
                            </v-col>
                            <v-col cols=1>
                                <v-btn @click="printAllPdf" elevation="8" height="75" width="80" class="ml-2" dark color="blue darken-3">Print<br/>All<br/>Tax<br/>Forms</v-btn>
                            </v-col>
                            <v-col class="my-0 ml-3 pa-0" cols=1>
                                 <v-radio-group v-model="radioGroup" >
                                  <v-radio value="Paid" label="Paid"></v-radio>
                                  <v-radio value="NSF" label="NSF"></v-radio>
                                 </v-radio-group>
                            </v-col>
                            <v-col class="ma-0 pa-0" cols=1>
                                <v-radio-group v-model="radioGroup">
                                  <v-radio value="Mistake" label="Mistake"></v-radio>
                                  <v-radio value="Duplicate" label="Duplicate"></v-radio>
                              </v-radio-group>
                            </v-col>
                            <v-col class="mr-2">
                                <v-textarea v-model="cbnotes" height="75" background-color="blue lighten-5" placeholder="Add Comments Here" dense  outlined class="my-0 mr-2"></v-textarea>
                            </v-col>
                            
                        </v-row>
                        
                        
                        </div>
                        </transition>
                    </template>```
````

````
      return {
          
          inputuser:' ',
          btndisabled:false,
          showpage:true,
          ipp:10,
          sar:"all",
          page: 1,
          radioGroup2:'Pending',
          cb:[],
          dab:false,
          cbnotes:'',
          radioGroup:'Paid',
          tab:'',
          search:'',
          dialogActivity:false,
          dialogActivity2:false,
          dialogActivityMsg:"",
          dialogActivityText:"",
          dialog:false,
          dialogmarkpaid:false,
          docno:"",
          acntno:"",
          note:"",
          activity:{loc:'',process:'',batchid:'',day:'',bat:'',ent:'',ending:'',per:'',type:'',code:'',tran:'',gross:'',Deduction:'',Exemption:'',Base:'',distrib:'',reference:''},
          newt:{batch:'',entry:'',reference:'',amount:'',code:'',status:'',comment:'',user:''},
          businessnotes:[],
          statusitems: ['pending', 'paid', 'bad check', 'paid online', 'lost in mail'],
          clickedon:{taxdetails:{"gross":0,"deductions":0,"exemptions":0,"taxableamount":0}},
          olpayments:[],
          printgroup:[],
          headers: [
          { text: 'Doc No.', value: 'prikey' },
          { text: 'Status', value: 'status' },
          {
            text: 'Account',
            align: 'start',
            value: 'accnt',
            
          },
          { text: 'Business', value: 'BusName' },
          { text: 'Log Date', value: 'calculatedate' },
          { text: 'Due Date', value: 'datedue' },
          { text: 'Tax Period', value: 'taxperiod' },
          { text: 'Total Tax', value: 'totaltax' },
          { text: 'Penalty', value: 'penalty' },
          { text: 'Prev Bal', value: 'balanceforward' },
          { text: 'Grand Total', value: 'grandtotal' },
        ],
      }
    }```
````

Comment: Do you need help formatting the code in your question?

Comment: I thought I put everything within the ``` ``` tag. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: There are spaces in front of the ticks, that's why it is not working. The ticks have to be the first thing on the line, optionally followed by the name of a syntax highlighter, which is the name of the language, i.e. ```css, ```html, etc. So you should format your code in your IDE and then copy it over between ```

Answer (score 0):

your cb property is not reactive. it is object, so without being reactive, 'cb' and 'cb.length' or other properties would not be reflected in your code/html.  let us go ahead it with ref

```
...,
cb : ref([]),
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply! I tried adding cb: ref([]) in my data section. I am now getting an error that says "undefined".

does the cb: ref([]) need to be in the v-checkbox v-model?

Comment: did you import the 'ref' from vue?
and commonly we use the reactive data in script like ```const cb = ref([]); ... return {cb}``` 
so we can manipulate/use the data not only in html part but also in script part..